# Go to Report on the Action. NO Back option

Tags: reporting-services

I have developed two SSRS reports. One is the Parent data. you can select a Department on a row and it will drill down to the second report. I am able to see the Back button on the Visual Studio 2019. But when I published it to the Portal, it is missing. Only way is use the back button on the browser.

This has fine in VS 2012. But not working on VS 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Add a textbox with "Go Back" text in it. Add a parameter call GoBack. Each time it is refreshed. Increment this Parameter GoBack.

On the Text box, ON the Action Use "Go to URL" and enter the below expression.
="javascript:history.go(-" + Parameters!GoBack.Value + ")"

This will fix the issue.